# What's the best way to allow a user to browse for a file in C#?

Tags: c#

What's the best way to allow a user to browse for a file in C#?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    dlg.Title = "Select a file";
    if (dlg.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //do something with dlg.FileName  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say use the standard "Open File" dialog box ([OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx)), this makes it less intimidating for new users and helps with a consistant UI.

Answer (score 1):

Close, Ryan, but you never showed the dialog.  it should be:

```
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```